# Can't clone repository from mounted drive

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and have a mounted microSD card that I've been able to clone repositories into in the past. Recently, however, I am receiving this error when I try to clone from `/mnt/d/`:

```
Cloning into 'your_repo'...
error: chmod on /mnt/d/your_repo/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /mnt/d/your_repo/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /mnt/d/your_repo/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /mnt/d/your_repo/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I change into any directory on `/mnt/c/` I can clone perfectly fine. When I clone I use SSH if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: There are some issue with SD cards. Try with a HDD or SSD. Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3519

Answer (score 51):

Considering changes to [Chmod/Chown WSL Improvements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/12/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/), you could try, as in [WSL issue 3172](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3172#issuecomment-389157376)

```
sudo umount /mnt/d
sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d -o metadata
```

Comment: great ! Work well

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: How to make it permanent, so that I don't need to do it again and again, Von? Thx

Comment: @xpt You should be able to put that command in your `~/.bashrc`, in order for your shell session to start by mounting that drive correctly (and automatically).

Answer (score 4):

I saw that error on a fresh WSL Unbuntu install. I could of course not `sudo umount /mnt/c`, however a reboot and all was well.